# Kendo UI MaskedTextBox write direction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, kendo-ui, telerik, maskedtextbox

I have had the following unexpected behavior in Kendo UI MVC MaskedEdit control: 
When I used with the respective mask works well in all browsers, but if control displays it in CHROME MOBILE with predictive text keyboard control activated behaves differently. 
When typing, the cursor is always positioned at the first position character. This results in a text written from right to left. Is this the correct behavior? How I can correct this behavior for writing usual on a mobile browser? This happens to me both in the pages that have developed **as well on DEMO page of TELERIK**.

I tried it with Samsung Galaxy S3, S4 and S5 with the same result.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/maskedtextbox/index

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Response from TELERIK..

> This is a known issue, which is already logged in our product backlog.
>   Unfortunately, we do not have any particular solution for this
>   specific problem in the aforementioned Samsumg devices. We have
>   scheduled the issue for further investigation and our goal is to solve
>   the problem for the next official release of Kendo UI.